# Check if all the buttons in an array are active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to check if all the buttons in an array are active or not, all at once? I am using for loop to determine it but the `break;` does not really signify anything that I want to achieve.

```
public Button[] bts;

public void StateButton()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bts.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (!bts[i].interactable)
        {
            Debug.Log("all buttons are off");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("atleast one is on");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "all buttons are off" is wrong. Your loop doesn't determine this; it only determines that at least one button is off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using LINQ:

```
var allInteractable = bts.All(e => e.interactable)
```

Depending on the length of the array and the expected state of the buttons (i.e. you know that almost all the time at least one button is not interactable) it might be more performant to inverse the query using:

```
var atLeastOneNonInteractable = bts.Any(e => !e.interactable)
```

Comment: I think internally they are pretty much equivalent in how they work and performance the first basically equals `foreach(var e in bts) { if(!e.interactable) { return false; } } return true;` while the second basically does the opposite `foreach(var e in bts){ if(e.interactable){ return true;} } return false;` ... so basically the performance would only depend on the index of the first button which doesn't match the condition

Comment: @derHugo Thats true. That is what I wanted to say. If he knows that almost all the time all buttons are interactable then I would use Any, otherwise All. But to be onest: I don't think there are so many buttons that there should be any performance considerations

Comment: That is probably true anyway ;) However, what I want to say is: It doesn't matter at all. The best case for both is you encounter an item (not) fulfilling the condition at index 0, worst case for `All` all items fulfill the condition and for `Any` no item fulfills the condition. The expectation about fulfilling the condition doesn't matter since any item in between can have the opposite of the expected value ... performance only depends on the index of that item. So which one you want to use is probably rather a decicion based on "whatever reads better in your context" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your debug logs don't really match with the title of your question.

Written out it should either be

```
public bool StateButton()
{
    var allOn = true;
 
    foreach (var btn in bts)
    {
        if (!btn.interactable)
        {
            allOn = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    Debug.Log(allOn ? "All buttons on" : "At least one button off");
    return allOn;
}
```

or

```
public bool StateButton()
{
    var anyOn = false;
 
    foreach (var btn in bts)
    {
        if (btn.interactable)
        {
            anyOn = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    Debug.Log(anyOn ? "At least one button on" : "All buttons off");
    return anyOn;
}
```

depending on your needs.

And then you already have [Michael Mairegger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69253072/7111561) using `Linq` to shorten this into a single line ;)